# Changing the elements along a diagonal

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I had a matrix like the one below:

```
1 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1
```

Is there a method to go through and replace the diagonal elements containing a 1 to a 0?

This is a simplified matrix, the one I am working with is actually 2965x2965 so I am hoping to apply the formula to that size of a matrix but only such that the diagonals change and everything else stays the same.

Comment: This is trivial with VBA. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not fluent with Excel and I am sure this would be a lot easier in a matrix language as well, but due to time constraints I can't pick it up. I tried playing around with an IF function but was unable to get it to work, and I have no experience coding in VBA.

Comment: Assuming the first item in your matrix is in cell `A1`, on `sheet1`, you could use: `=IF(ROW(A1)=COLUMN(A1),0,A1)` in cell `A1` of `sheet2`. You can then populate the formula on the same number of rows and columns as you have in `sheet1`

Comment: I found some VBA code:

Sub ClearDiagonal()
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim I As Long
    
    Set rng = Range("A1:Z26")
    
    Set c = rng.Cells(1, 1)
    
    For I = 0 To rng.Rows.Count - 1
        
        c.ClearContents
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 1)
    Next I
    
End Sub

It will replace the elements along the diagonal with a blank cell, but then one can use 'find and replace' to then repopulate the blank cells in the range (the diagonal) with the same values (in this case a 0). Although, would be interested to hear of other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but this appears to do what you need:

```
Sub OneToZero()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Columns.Count
    For i = 1 To N
        If Cells(i, i).Value = 1 Then Cells(i, i) = 0
    Next i
End Sub
```